# Overriding external CSS rules for a jquery menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a page layout which works fine and it's one that I don't want to mess with (unless I have to).  I'm not adept at javascript so I found an example online.  The problem I'm getting is that when using my accordion menu, the submenu is offset to the right.  I used some inline CSS in the html itself and used the `!important` command to override the automatic padding that's on the list elements.  This doesn't seem to be having any effect. JS fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aqeFd/1/).  There's tons of autogenerated commented code in there so it's going to be messy, I just needed all of it to show the example of what the accordion submenu looks like.  Why isn't the inline CSS overriding the external CSS file?  Why isn't the `!important` keyword working?

I thought there was some padding going on but
`ul { 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}`
 is in my external CSS file, and padding is obviously set to 0.

Here is the CSS that makes the accordion work.

```
<style type="text/css">
#accordionNav {
    float: left;
    width: 560px;
    list-style:none;

    padding:none;
}
#accordionNav li a {
    display: block;
    padding:5px;
    background: #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    list-style:none;
    padding:none !important;

    width: 560px;
}
#accordionNav li a:hover, #accordionNav li a.active {
    background: #999;
    color: #fff;
}
#accordionNav li ul {
    display: none; 
    list-style:none;
    padding:none !important;

}
#accordionNav li ul li a {
    padding:0 0 0;
    background: #ececec;
    list-style:none;
    padding:none !important;

}
```

Any idea what it could be that's keeping the sub menu from aligning properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used:

```
padding: none !important;
```

instead of

```
padding: 0 !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `padding: none;` for `padding: 0`.